# Images not showing when using fields() in bolt CMS

Tags: php, twig, bolt-cms

I have the following code in my record twig file:

```
<article class="indivisual-article-writeup">    
<h1>{{ record.title }}</h1>
  {# Output all fields, in the order as defined in the contenttype.
      To change the generated html and configure the options, see:
       https://docs.bolt.cm/templating/fields-tag #}
    {{ fields() }}

    {# Uncomment this if you wish to dump the entire record to the client, for debugging purposes.
       {{ dump(record) }}
    #}
</article>
```

Now one of the elements of `{{ fields() }}` is an image and so i get a broken link.

**Also**,  I added an image to the about us  block , now when i just wanted to output the feilds of the about-us record so i added the following code to test it:

```
{% setcontent block = "block/about-us" %}
{{ fields(block) }}
```

Now even here the image field shows as a broken link , but when i have my CMS uploaded to the server everything seems to work fine. Why is this happening ??

Whats the remedy to this ?

Comment: A guess, local xampp is missing some extension which is used to create thumbnails or otherwise modified versions of your image. Or maybe the CMS tries to extract information from the image and fails at that, which again results in no image displayed.
As it works on the server but not local, I would carefully compare output of phpinfo() and crosscheck with requirements from Bolt CMS.

Comment: Check gd, fileinfo and exif. I suppose they should be available.